# How to let user access firestore authenticated in different firebase project

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

Can anyone please help me.
I have one firebase project A and rules are set like only authenticated use can access data.
But I have some more users who are authenticated in another firebase project B need access to the to the firebase project A.
How can I implement that. I am using email, Facebook and Google authentication.

Comment: Can you share some of the code you have so far to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry but only setup what I am currently with is that I made the read write permission true for all in firebase project setting , so that from outside project any one can access. I am afraid this is a potential risk, any one can get through.